# How to get rid of parenthesis that appears in year on the reference list using dcu.bst Harvard citation style?

Tags: bibtex

I am using `\bibliographystyle{dcu}` for Harvard style citation, I want to get rid of the parenthesis from the `dcu.bst` file. How can I remove the `()` parenthesis around the year that appears in the reference list?

I am asking because I am not seeing the parenthesis around a year in the source code i.e, `dcu.bst` file.

You can find the code here: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/dcu.bst

Thank you for your help in advance. Following is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,color}  
\usepackage[comma, authoryear]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}} 
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{final.bib}
@article{jan,
  title={{A simulation toolkit }},
  author={Donald Donald},
  journal={Phys. Med. Biol.},
  volume={\textcolor{blue}{xx}},
  pages={\textcolor{blue}{101-110}},
  year={2004},
  publisher={IOP Publishing}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\section{Intro}
Hello, this is a simple example of harvard style citation~\cite{jan}.
\bibliography{final}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

1. I want to remove the parenthesis in the reference but not in the context as shown in Intro part.
2. Also want to get rid of dot appears in the end of the reference.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  Linking to files that are part of the standard distributions is not really necessary. But for future questions it's much more helpful to post a minimal compilable document showing what you're actually doing (as in my answer.)

Comment: Using the `dcu` style for this is not really appropriate, since there are too many differences that you want to change. You can make your own `.bst` file using `makebst`. Or switch to using `biblatex` which makes adapting styles somewhat simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The `dcu` bibliography style is part of the `natbib` set of bibliography styles. The parentheses are set by `natbib` not by the `.bst` file itself.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Chomsky1965,
    Address = {Cambridge Mass.},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    Title = {Aspects of the Theory of Syntax},
    Year = {1965}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{open={},close={}}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\begin{document}
\citet{Chomsky1965}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score -1):

@Alan, Thank you for your help. I now understand that I was missing \setcitestyle{open={},close={}}.

Also, I want to remove the dot after the year and at the end of the reference. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi Ashok, please don't use the answer box for a comment or to ask a followup question. Instead post a comment on the answer.

Comment: @Alan, Thank you for your help. However,`\setcitestyle{open={},close={}}` get rid of the parenthesis in the year in reference but also removes the parenthesis in the cited text in the context, which I want to keep as (Chomsky 1965).

Also, I want to remove the dot after the year and at the end of the reference. How can I do that?